# Show that the Stieltjes measure is left-continuous

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $\mu[-n, n)<\infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} .$ Show that
$$
F_{\mu}(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mu[0, x) & \text { if } x>0 \\
0 & \text { if } x=0 \\
-\mu[x, 0) & \text { if } x<0
\end{array}\right.
$$
is a monotonically increasing and left-continuous function $F_{\mu}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. **Remark**: Increasing and left-continuous functions are called Stieltjes functions.

---

I have showed that it is monotonically increasing.

I now have to show that it is left-continuous. I'm thinking that I have to split this in some cases. The first case will be $x > 0$.

So I will like to show that $F_\mu$ is left-continuous at a point $a>x$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to{a^- }}F_\mu(x)=F(a)$. Or equally $\lim_{x\to{a^- }}\mu[0,x)=\mu[0,a)$. I'm thinking of writing $A=[0,a)$ such that $A_{n} \uparrow A$. Then I could use the property of $\mu$:

$$
A_{n} \uparrow A \Longrightarrow \mu(A)=\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu\left(A_{n}\right)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu\left(A_{n}\right) \quad \text { (continuous from below) }
$$

If this is correct, then what is left for me is to translate the limit $x\to{a^-}$ to $n\to{a^-}$. And since $F_\mu$ is increasing then I can use the fact that these two limits are the same. My problem is that I have a hard time translating between these two limits. (?)

edit: I could maybe also use the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to{a^- }}\mu[0,x)=\mu[0,a) \iff \lim_{x\to{a^-}}x=a$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F_{\mu}$ is not left  continuous at $a$ then there exist $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $\delta >0$ there exists $x$ with $a-\delta <x<a$ and $|F_{\mu}(x)-f(a)| \geq \epsilon$. Take $\delta=\frac  1 n$ to get $x_n$ such that $a-\frac 1  n<x<a$ and $|F_{\mu}(x_n)-f(a)| \geq \epsilon$. Take $A_n=[0,x_n)$ in your argument to finish the proof.